# State Not Changing Properly In React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React Redux I have initialized state which is properly displaying by calling its respective reducer which job to return the initialize State. But after mutating the state the state most probably not changing and i cant figure it out why

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const initialState = {
    songs:[
        {title:'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05'},
    ]
}

const songReducers = (state = initialState)=>{
    return state
}

const selectedSongReducer =(selectedSong=null,action)=>{
    if(action.type==='SONG_SELECTED'){
        return action.payload
    }

    return selectedSong;
}


const addSongReducer = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    if(action.type==="ADD_SONG"){
       return {
        ...state,   
        songs:[
           ...state.songs, {title:'All demo', duration: '4:05'}
        ]
    }
    }
    return state;
}

export default combineReducers({
    songs: songReducers,
    selectedSong: selectedSongReducer,
    addSong:addSongReducer
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your overall state shape will look like

```
state = {
    songs: {
        songs: [
            { title: 'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05' },
        ]
    },
    selectedSong: null,
    addSong: {
        songs: [
            { title: 'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05' },
        ]
    }
}
```

after the very first reducer call. Is this what you want? Asking because you have

```
state = {
    songs: {
        songs: [
            { title: 'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05' },
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

instead of just

```
state = {
    songs: [
        { title: 'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05' },
    ]
    ...
}
```